# Is there a way to explicitly disable rounded borders on PDFBox's text annotations?

Tags: java, firefox, annotations, pdfbox, pdf.js

I'm using PDFBox to highlight regions of a PDF. I need these regions to appear behind text so I'm using `PDAnnotationTextMarkup` with `SUB_TYPE_HIGHLIGHT`.

I've noticed that when I `constructAppearances`, the highlights show with rounded borders in PDF.js / Firefox which isn't what I want. They appear with straight borders if I don't `constructAppearances` but then I worry about compatibility.

Is there a way to explicitly set a 'straight' border style on the text annotations? I couldn't [see a method](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.7/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/interactive/annotation/PDAnnotationTextMarkup.html) for this. Hopefully this isn't a quirk of PDF.js / Firefox that I am unable to control.

Thanks

Comment: The existing code tries to get close to the user experience with Adobe. You would have to write your own annotation handler if you don't like that. See the source code of PDHighlightAppearanceHandler.java, make your own, and pass it to your annotation by calling "setCustomAppearanceHandler()"

Comment: Thanks. I had a quick look at this before settling on a slightly hacky workaround which is to split the annotations up into narrow strips. The border radius problem is less noticeable when not very tall.